# Is the orientation attribute in relative layout responsible to make any changes to the final layout view obtained?

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, android-relativelayout

I have been trying to preview the layout for the given `XML` code in android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
android:background="@color/tan_background"    
tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.ColorsActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image">
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzhir.png 
But now I find that whenever I am trying to remove the orientation attribute from the relative layout parent view group of the same code(correct me If I am wrong in describing it), I find that the same preview is being obtained.
The view obtained after doing the above-mentioned change is as shown here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNbKF.png .Does this mean that it doesn't matter if we are putting any orientation attribute in the relative layout or not? Or are there any hidden consequences in the orientation attribute of the relative layout in XML in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), there is no orientation argument for `RelativeLayout`.